# How to hide h:selectOneListbox component using ajax after click?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<h:selectOneListbox>` that appears when a `<h:commandbutton>` is clicked. When the user selects from the listbox I want the selected value to appear in a `<h:inputText>` and hide the listbox.

I can't make the `<h:selectoneListbox>` stop rendering once it appears. The `rendered` attribute works fine when the view first appears, but is ignored after I click the list and the listener is invoked.

Any ideas?

Here is the Facelet:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:inputText id="TitleText" value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.title}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Clients" actionListener= #bindingScheduleHandler.clientList}" />

    <h:selectOneListbox id="listBox" value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clients}" size="5"  
        rendered="#{bindingScheduleHandler.showClients}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clientLabelsValues}" />
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clickListener}"  
            render="TitleText" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Here is the backing bean:

```
public void clickListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    this.title = clients;
    showClients = false;
    renderClientList = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<f:ajax render>`, you can't refer components which are conditionally rendered by JSF. Instead, you need to refer a parent component which is **always** rendered. The simple explanation is that the `<f:ajax>` is using JavaScript to update the content (the node value) of the HTML element as represented by the JSF component. It isn't possible to show/hide the HTML element itself.

Just update a parent component instead.

```
<h:panelGroup id="group">
    <h:inputText id="TitleText" value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.title}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Clients" actionListener= #bindingScheduleHandler.clientList}" />

    <h:selectOneListbox id="listBox" value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clients}" size="5"  
        rendered="#{bindingScheduleHandler.showClients}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clientLabelsValues}" />
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bindingScheduleHandler.clickListener}"  
            render="group" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This will by the way also instantly fix the problem of the selected item not being displayed in the `<h:inputText>` :)